# Any way to make a sync get call?

Tags: java, android

I'm retrieving some information from the server using REST. I make a Get call using AsyncTask. But I need to wait for the results... Is there any way to do it synchronously? So I can get the result.

Code:

```
private void sendStuff(Context context, String[] params) {
    RESTGet restGet = new RESTGet(context);
    restGet.setMessageLoading("Loading...");
    try {
        restGet.execute(params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    restGet.stopMessageLoading();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowPictures.class);
    ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: You may want to rethink your design if you need to wait for a response from a server. As if it takes over a few seconds Android would certainly Force Close your app.

Comment: I understand, but I need to know when it ends to call the next line. Just in one specific case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get() to wait for the task to end and even get its result. But I would not recommend this, because it will freeze your app.
Example assuming that RESTGet extends AsyncTask:

```
private void sendStuff(Context context, String[] params) {
    final int TIMEOUT = 2000;

    RESTGet restGet = new RESTGet(context);
    restGet.setMessageLoading("Loading...");
    try {
        restGet.execute(params).get(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    restGet.stopMessageLoading();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowPictures.class);
    ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
}
```

Instead of using get, put your code in onPostExecute method, so it will be called after the task execution.
Ex:

```
private void sendStuff(Context context, String[] params) {
    RESTGet restGet = new RESTGet(context) {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
            super.onPostExecute(feed);
            this.stopMessageLoading();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowPictures.class);
            ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.execute(params);
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: How do I call onPostExecute?

Comment: It will be called by AsyncTask automatically at the end of execution of your code.